# ESP-IDF Compile error while Building CXX object file. ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed

Tags: c++, esp32, freertos, ninja, esp-idf

I have run into a wall while compiling my ESP-IDF project on Mac OS.Every time I do “idf.py build” the compiler runs but the process gets terminated due to a missing file in the ESP-IDF folder inside the Build folder. I can’t seem to figure out the problem that’s causing it. I have attached the error logs with this post if anyone could please take a look and tell me what could be the potential fix for this issue?

Moreover, when I build the same code on a Windows machine, it builds successfully without a problem. I have tried different versions of the ESP-IDF to make sure the version is not a problem. I am new to this and out of ideas to try a fix. I would appreciate the help thank in advance guys!!

```
[1281/1689] Building CXX object esp-idf/Test_Code/CMakeFiles/idf_Test_Code.dir///Babelfish/Code/MiscCode/Esp32_Partition.cpp.obj FAILED: esp-idf/Test_Code/CMakeFiles/idf_Test_Code.dir///Babelfish/Code/MiscCode/Esp32_Partition.cpp.obj /Users/E0729952/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-g++ -DESP32_SETUP -DFREERTOS_V10 -DIOT_SAS_TOKEN_REFRESH_SECS=86400 -DNV_CRYPTO -DPKI_SUPPORT -DPX_GREEN_IOT_DEVICE -DPX_GREEN_IOT_SUPPORT -DRTC_INTERFACE -DSNTP_SETUP -DUSE_CLIENT_SIDE_SSL -DWIFI_STATION_MODE -I/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/build/config -I/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/Code -I/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/Code/Config -I/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/Code/Shell -I/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/Code/BFData -I/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/Babelfish/Code/uC -I/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/Babelfish/Code/uC/ESP32D0WD -I/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/Babelfish/Code/uC/Generic -I/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/Babelfish/Code/Lib -I/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/Babelfish/Code/OS_FreeRTOS -I/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/Babelfish/Code/BF -I/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/Babelfish/Code/NV -I/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/Babelfish/Code/BF/Wifi -I/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/Babelfish/Code/BF/DCI -I/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/Babelfish/Code/DebugManager -I/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/Babelfish/Code/Ethernet -I/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/Babelfish/Code/MiscCode -I/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/Babelfish/Code/MiscCode/FUS -I/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/esp32_common/esp-idf/components/freertos/include/freertos -I/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/esp32_common/esp-idf/components/esp_system/include/esp_private -I/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/esp32_common/esp-idf/components/esp_common/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/esp32_common/esp-idf/components/spi_flash/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/esp32_common/esp-idf/components/xtensa/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/esp32_common/esp-idf/components/driver/include/driver -I/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/esp32_common/esp-idf/components/bootloader_support/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/esp32_common/esp-idf/components/app_update/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/esp32_common/esp-idf/tools/unit-test-app/components/test_utils/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/esp32_common/esp-idf/components/idf_test/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/esp32_common/esp-idf/components/esp32/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/esp32_common/esp-idf/components/idf_test/include/esp32 -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/newlib/platform_include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/freertos/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/freertos/include/esp_additions/freertos -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/freertos/port/xtensa/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/freertos/include/esp_additions -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/include/soc -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/include/soc/esp32 -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/port/esp32/. -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/port/esp32/private_include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/heap/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/log/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/lwip/include/apps -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/lwip/include/apps/sntp -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/lwip/lwip/src/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/lwip/port/esp32/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/lwip/port/esp32/include/arch -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/soc/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/soc/esp32/. -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/soc/esp32/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/hal/esp32/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/hal/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/hal/platform_port/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/include/esp32 -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32 -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/esp_common/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/esp_system/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/esp_system/port/soc -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/esp_system/port/public_compat -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/esp32/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/xtensa/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/xtensa/esp32/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/driver/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/driver/esp32/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/esp_pm/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/esp_ringbuf/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/efuse/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/efuse/esp32/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/vfs/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/esp_wifi/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/esp_event/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/esp_netif/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/esp_eth/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/tcpip_adapter/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/esp_phy/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/esp_phy/esp32/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/esp_ipc/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/app_trace/include -I/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf/components/esp_timer/include -mlongcalls -Wno-frame-address -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -Werror=all -Wno-error=unused-function -Wno-error=unused-variable -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-compare -ggdb -Os -freorder-blocks -fmacro-prefix-map=/Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32=. -fmacro-prefix-map=/Users/E0729952/work/esp-idf=IDF -fstrict-volatile-bitfields -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable -fno-jump-tables -fno-tree-switch-conversion -std=gnu++11 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -D_GNU_SOURCE -DIDF_VER="-128-NOTFOUND" -DESP_PLATFORM -DNDEBUG -D_POSIX_READER_WRITER_LOCKS -MD -MT esp-idf/Test_Code/CMakeFiles/idf_Test_Code.dir///Babelfish/Code/MiscCode/Esp32_Partition.cpp.obj -MF esp-idf/Test_Code/CMakeFiles/idf_Test_Code.dir///Babelfish/Code/MiscCode/Esp32_Partition.cpp.obj.d -o esp-idf/Test_Code/CMakeFiles/idf_Test_Code.dir//__/Babelfish/Code/MiscCode/Esp32_Partition.cpp.obj -c /Users/E0729952/work/sb2fw-communication-esp32/Babelfish/Code/MiscCode/Esp32_Partition.cpp

***down at the very bottom....


[1298/1689] Building CXX object esp-idf/TimeConversion/CMakeFiles/__idf_TimeConversion.dir/test_time.cpp.obj
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
ninja failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: What IDF version are you using? Could you show the full error log, please? The log you posted is only the compiler call, the rest of the compiler error is left out.

BTW., you might have more luck and quicker answers if you post in the esp32.com forum.